# Drag and Drop in Angular without Removing from Origional Container

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am copying an element from one container to another in angular.while copying it temperory gets remove from the Origional container and gets copied.Is there a way it doesnt get temporary removed from origional container and still gets copied?

I tried to Did Some Research and found it could be done with cdkDragStarted and CdkDragStopped, but i am unable to implement it properly! Here is the demo code on which i want to implement to further use it in my main Project

```
//HtMl

<div class="container">
  <h2>Movies</h2>
  <div 
  cdkDropList 
  #moviesList="cdkDropList" 
  [cdkDropListData]="MoviesList"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneMovieList]" 
  class="movie-list" 
  (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
  <div class="movie-block" *ngFor="let moviesList of MoviesList" cdkDrag>{{moviesList}}</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Movies Watched</h2>
  <div 
  cdkDropList 
  #doneMovieList="cdkDropList" 
  [cdkDropListData]="MoviesWatched"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[moviesList]" 
  class="movie-list" 
  (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
  <div class="movie-block" *ngFor="let moviesWatched of MoviesWatched" cdkDrag>{{moviesWatched}}</div>
</div>
</div>

//CSS

.wrapper {
    margin: 25px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .movie-list {
    width: 80%;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    min-height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .movie-block {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: move;
    background: white;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .cdk-drag-preview {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
      0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
  .cdk-drag-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .cdk-drag-animating {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
  .movie-block:last-child {
    border: none;
  }
  .movie-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .movie-block:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }

.wrapper {
    margin: 25px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .movie-list {
    width: 80%;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    min-height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .movie-block {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: move;
    background: white;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .cdk-drag-preview {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
      0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
  .cdk-drag-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .cdk-drag-animating {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
  .movie-block:last-child {
    border: none;
  }
  .movie-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .movie-block:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }

//TS

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, CdkDragStart, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // Transfer Items Between Lists
  MoviesList:any = [
    'The Far Side of the World',
    'Morituri',
    'Napoleon Dynamite',
    'Pulp Fiction',
    'Blade Runner',
    'Cool Hand Luke',
    'Heat',
    'Juice'
  ];
  MoviesWatched:any = [
  ];
  onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }  





}
```

Comment: Please provide some more details about hos it isn't working. What is the current behavior, what do you expect the behavior to be?

Comment: hey Kevon , let me take You To the page
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists
in #transferring-items-between-lists  , when i pick one item and drag as soon as my mouse pointer touches the destination (Done) container item gets automatically removed from the Source(To do) list. i want the item to stay until i drop the mouse .

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Use the `copyArrayItem()` method instead of
`transferArrayItem()` method. And it will work as well.

**Use this:**

```
...
copyArrayItem(
  event.previousContainer.data,
  event.container.data,
  event.previousIndex,
  event.currentIndex
);
...
```